# Getting "... 23 more" instead of full error in Spring-boot application

Tags: java, spring-boot, logging, error-handling

I'm getting an error in an Spring-boot application. I'm trying to catch it and work with it but I'm not able to do it and in the logs I only see a part of the error.

Error in logs:

```
com.amazonaws.SdkClientException: Unable to execute HTTP request: Connect to localhost:3128 [/localhost] failed: Connect timed out
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.handleRetryableException(AmazonHttpClient.java:1113) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.207.jar!/:?]
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:1063) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.207.jar!/:?]
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.doExecute(AmazonHttpClient.java:743) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.207.jar!/:?]
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeWithTimer(AmazonHttpClient.java:717) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.207.jar!/:?]
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:699) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.207.jar!/:?]
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.access$500(AmazonHttpClient.java:667) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.207.jar!/:?]
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutionBuilderImpl.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:649) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.207.jar!/:?]
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:513) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.207.jar!/:?]
    at com.amazonaws.services.sqs.AmazonSQSClient.doInvoke(AmazonSQSClient.java:1740) ~[aws-java-sdk-sqs-1.11.207.jar!/:?]
    at com.amazonaws.services.sqs.AmazonSQSClient.invoke(AmazonSQSClient.java:1716) ~[aws-java-sdk-sqs-1.11.207.jar!/:?]
    at com.amazonaws.services.sqs.AmazonSQSClient.executeDeleteMessageBatch(AmazonSQSClient.java:873) ~[aws-java-sdk-sqs-1.11.207.jar!/:?]
    at com.amazonaws.services.sqs.AmazonSQSClient.deleteMessageBatch(AmazonSQSClient.java:849) ~[aws-java-sdk-sqs-1.11.207.jar!/:?]
    at com.amazon.sqs.javamessaging.AmazonSQSMessagingClientWrapper.deleteMessageBatch(AmazonSQSMessagingClientWrapper.java:168) [amazon-sqs-java-messaging-lib-1.0.3.jar!/:?]
    at com.amazon.sqs.javamessaging.acknowledge.RangedAcknowledger.action(RangedAcknowledger.java:142) [amazon-sqs-java-messaging-lib-1.0.3.jar!/:?]
    at com.amazon.sqs.javamessaging.acknowledge.BulkSQSOperation.bulkAction(BulkSQSOperation.java:61) [amazon-sqs-java-messaging-lib-1.0.3.jar!/:?]
    at com.amazon.sqs.javamessaging.acknowledge.RangedAcknowledger.acknowledge(RangedAcknowledger.java:66) [amazon-sqs-java-messaging-lib-1.0.3.jar!/:?]
    at com.amazon.sqs.javamessaging.message.SQSMessage.acknowledge(SQSMessage.java:920) [amazon-sqs-java-messaging-lib-1.0.3.jar!/:?]
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.commitIfNecessary(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:780) [spring-jms-5.3.18.jar!/:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doExecuteListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:680) [spring-jms-5.3.18.jar!/:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.doReceiveAndExecute(AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.java:331) [spring-jms-5.3.18.jar!/:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.receiveAndExecute(AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.java:270) [spring-jms-5.3.18.jar!/:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.invokeListener(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1237) [spring-jms-5.3.18.jar!/:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.executeOngoingLoop(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1227) [spring-jms-5.3.18.jar!/:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.run(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1120) [spring-jms-5.3.18.jar!/:5.3.18]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832) [?:?]
Caused by: org.apache.http.conn.ConnectTimeoutException: Connect to localhost:3128 [/localhost] failed: Connect timed out
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:151) ~[httpclient-4.5.13.jar!/:4.5.13]
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:376) ~[httpclient-4.5.13.jar!/:4.5.13]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor75.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564) ~[?:?]
    at com.amazonaws.http.conn.ClientConnectionManagerFactory$Handler.invoke(ClientConnectionManagerFactory.java:76) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.207.jar!/:?]
    at com.amazonaws.http.conn.$Proxy125.connect(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:401) ~[httpclient-4.5.13.jar!/:4.5.13]
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:236) ~[httpclient-4.5.13.jar!/:4.5.13]
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:186) ~[httpclient-4.5.13.jar!/:4.5.13]
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:185) ~[httpclient-4.5.13.jar!/:4.5.13]
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:83) ~[httpclient-4.5.13.jar!/:4.5.13]
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:56) ~[httpclient-4.5.13.jar!/:4.5.13]
    at com.amazonaws.http.apache.client.impl.SdkHttpClient.execute(SdkHttpClient.java:72) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.207.jar!/:?]
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeOneRequest(AmazonHttpClient.java:1235) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.207.jar!/:?]
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:1055) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.207.jar!/:?]
    ... 23 more
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Connect timed out
    at sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.timedFinishConnect(NioSocketImpl.java:546) ~[?:?]
    at sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.connect(NioSocketImpl.java:597) ~[?:?]
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:333) ~[?:?]
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:648) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.http.conn.socket.PlainConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainConnectionSocketFactory.java:75) ~[httpclient-4.5.13.jar!/:4.5.13]
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:142) ~[httpclient-4.5.13.jar!/:4.5.13]
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:376) ~[httpclient-4.5.13.jar!/:4.5.13]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor75.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564) ~[?:?]
    at com.amazonaws.http.conn.ClientConnectionManagerFactory$Handler.invoke(ClientConnectionManagerFactory.java:76) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.207.jar!/:?]
    at com.amazonaws.http.conn.$Proxy125.connect(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:401) ~[httpclient-4.5.13.jar!/:4.5.13]
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:236) ~[httpclient-4.5.13.jar!/:4.5.13]
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:186) ~[httpclient-4.5.13.jar!/:4.5.13]
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:185) ~[httpclient-4.5.13.jar!/:4.5.13]
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:83) ~[httpclient-4.5.13.jar!/:4.5.13]
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:56) ~[httpclient-4.5.13.jar!/:4.5.13]
    at com.amazonaws.http.apache.client.impl.SdkHttpClient.execute(SdkHttpClient.java:72) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.207.jar!/:?]
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeOneRequest(AmazonHttpClient.java:1235) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.207.jar!/:?]
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:1055) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.207.jar!/:?]
    ... 23 more
```

I tried to put logs and `try-catch` blocks everywhere in the code, nothing seems to work. I simply cannot identify where this error occurs. I thought of getting the exact line where this happens in the logs, but instead of the entire error, I'm getting the above error displaying some `... 23 more`.

How can I display the entire error message?

Comment: It's because that line in the stack is already there at a higher level. There is no point in repeating it. `RequestExecutor.executeHelper` is called by `RequestExecutor.doExecute`, as indicated by lines 3 and 4 of what you posted

Comment: I was thinking of getting to the point where I see the line number in the execution where the error is thrown in the application. I understand that `doExecute` is where it happens, I thought the track will also show where that happens in the code of the application. Like, displaying the line number of the implementation of that library

Comment: Not sure what you are getting at. The next line of the omitted trace would be `doExecute(AmazonHttpClient.java:743)`. If you look at the implementation, you'll find that's the *only* place executeHelper is called from anyway. There is no other option. As I already said, the trace which is omitted is identical to the trace that's above it. That's precisely the reason that it's able to be omitted.

Comment: Also not sure what you think you'll be able to fix by knowing the trace that happens 20 calls deep into framework code anyway. The connection is timing out. Likely because the application you're trying to connect to is busy or hung or something.

Comment: So all the modules you're seeing in the error are actually external libraries. I had the same issue with some other tool (the connection is to a proxy server and it drops time by time) and I solved it by adding a re-try function where the error happened. I want to trace this error to the moment it intersects with my code so I can add that re-try function there

Comment: Again, to be completely explicit: none of the omitted lines are your application code. How is that possible? Well, a stack is only for one thread. As an example, your application might dump some request onto a queue, which the framework picks up on its own thread. Your application code would never be in the stack trace for such a thread.